# "Inverse" UIImage from NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsattributedstring, uigraphicscontext

I create a `UIImage` from an `NSAttributedString`:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f];
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:font,
                             NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor greenColor]};

NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:attributes];

// Create the image here
UIImage *image = [self imageFromAttributedString:attributedString];


#pragma mark - Get image from attributed string

- (UIImage *)imageFromAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)text
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(text.size, NO, 0.0);

    // draw in context
    [text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)];

    // transfer image
    UIImage *image = [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

My question is, what's the best way to create an image with the same text, but "reversed", i.e. [UIColor greenColor] with white font text?

Comment: 1) Create the string the opposite way to begin with.  2) Parse the string and reverse the color info in it.  3) Filter the image, extract the dominant colors, and interchange them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName` to set background for green and `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` the text to white.

The docs include:

```
NSString *const NSForegroundColorAttributeName;
NSString *const NSBackgroundColorAttributeName;
```

at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011688

Answer (score 0):

Once you have an image you can use Core Image Filters to reverse the colour or change blue to pink or red or whatever you wish:   There is a CI Filter called CIColorInvert which will simply reverse the colours but personally I prefer using the colorMatrix filter which gives me more control code to reverse are the following:

> Note this routine assumes your starting UIImage is beginImage the output is endImage

Using ColorMatrix:

```
 CIFilter *filterci = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMatrix"  //rgreen
                                keysAndValues: kCIInputImageKey, beginImage, nil];
[filterci setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:-1 Y:0 Z:0 W:0] forKey:@"inputRVector"]; // 5
[filterci setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:-1 Z:0 W:0] forKey:@"inputGVector"]; // 6
[filterci setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0 Z:-1 W:0] forKey:@"inputBVector"]; // 7
[filterci setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0 Z:0 W:1] forKey:@"inputAVector"]; // 8
[filterci setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0 Z:0 W:0] forKey:@"inputBiasVector"];     
 CIImage *boutputImagei = [filterci outputImage];

  CGImageRef cgimgi = [context createCGImage:boutputImagei fromRect:[boutputImage extent]];
UIImage *endImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimgi];

 CGImageRelease(cgimgi);
```

Using CIColorInvert:

```
CIFilter *filterci = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorInvert"  //rgreen
                                keysAndValues: kCIInputImageKey, beginImage, nil];
    CIImage *boutputImagei = [filterci outputImage];

  CGImageRef cgimgi = [context createCGImage:boutputImagei fromRect:[boutputImage extent]];
UIImage *endImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimgi];

 CGImageRelease(cgimgi);
```